# Align object to face (walk on terrain)

Tags: three.js

I can't wrap my head around this and was hoping someone might be able to help me. I have an object3D which is being placed on a terrain (plane mesh). I create a Ray, positioned at the object but really high, and find the intersection point into the terrain (essentially the `Y` intersection). Once I have that I position the object on the terrain at that position.

From the intersect object function I also get the Face which contains the normal at that point. What I'd like to do is align the mesh so that it has the same rotation as the point its standing on.

Once the object is aligned with the world I also need it to face a target its heading towards. Currently I'm using the lookAt function to achieve this.

So I guess my question is two parts. The first is how to align the object with the world. And the second is, how to get that object to face a target without messing up the calculation of the first? (I guess this could be achieved with a child node? The parent node aligned to the world and the sub-mesh node looking at the target?)

Thanks guys
Mat